# Using a Kalman filter to predict samples between measurements

Tags: kalman-filters, c++

(cross posted from stack overflow)
I have a dataset where measurements were taken at 10 Hz, and I am trying to use a Kalman filter to add predicted samples in between the measurements, so that my output is at 100 Hz. I have it working ok when the velocity is linear, but when the direction changes, the filter takes a while to catch up. I am new to Kalman models, so am very likely making some mistakes in my settings. See [image](https://imghost.io/image/dI9va)

for an example, the red is measured data, with stepping in between measurements. The blue is the Kalman corrected.

std::vector measurements is a dummy data array I am testing with.

The main Kalman code is based on this:

https://github.com/hmartiro/kalman-cpp/blob/master/kalman.cpp

Am I correct in feeding the prediction back into the filter for every loop? Or is this line:

`yPos << kf.state().transpose();` wrong?

my code is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int n = 3; // Number of states
  int m = 1; // Number of measurements

  double dt = 1.0/30; // Time step

  Eigen::MatrixXd matA(n, n); // System dynamics matrix
  Eigen::MatrixXd matC(m, n); // Output matrix
  Eigen::MatrixXd matQ(n, n); // Process noise covariance
  Eigen::MatrixXd matR(m, m); // Measurement noise covariance
  Eigen::MatrixXd matP(n, n); // Estimate error covariance

  // Discrete motion, measuring position only
  matA << 1, dt, 0, 0, 1, dt, 0, 0, 1;
  matC << 1, 0, 0;

  // Reasonable covariance matrices
  matQ << 0.001, 0.001, .0, 0.001, 0.001, .0, .0, .0, .0;
  matR << 0.03;
  matP << .1, .1, .1, .1, 10000, 10, .1, 10, 100;

  // Construct the filter
  KalmanFilter kf(dt,matA, matC, matQ, matR, matP);

  // List of noisy position measurements (yPos)
  std::vector<double> measurements = {
     10,11,13,13.5,14,15.2,15.6,16,18,22,20,21,19,18,17,16,17.5,19,21,22,23,25,26,25,24,21,20,18,16
  };

  // Best guess of initial states
  Eigen::VectorXd x0(n);
  x0 << measurements[0], 0, 0;
  kf.init(dt,x0);

  // Feed measurements into filter, output estimated states
  double t = 0;
  Eigen::VectorXd y(m);


  for(int i = 0; i < measurements.size(); i++) { //ACTUAL MEASURED SAMPLE

      yPos << measurements[i];

      kf.update(yPos);

      for (int ji = 0; ji < 10; ji++)  // TEN PREDICTED SAMPLES
      {
          t += dt;       

         kf.update(yPos);


          yPos << kf.state().transpose(); //USE PREDICTION AS NEW SAMPLE

      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry that it was not very clear to me what you were asking. But I think I have developed some sense on it as follows:

You are physically capturing 10 noisy sensor measurements per second, which I call it as the **physical** measurements. But for some reasons, you want to fill in between those true-physical data samples with new synthetic data, generated **mathematically** at a rate of 100 samples per second (10 times more dense than available with the physical sensor measurement)

The solution to this problem has different names, based on your interpretation and which method you choose to follow, such as a **sampler**, a  **predictor**, an **estimator**, a **curve fitting** or an **interpolation**...

It seems, you want to use a Kalman filter (an estimator actually) to generate those new synthetic samples in between the true physical measurements. And your question is whether you should feed those synthetically generated new sampes back into the Kalman filter (for residual calculations) as if the data were generated from a true physical sensor, so that the filter can use it in residual calculations to get rid of the noise present in it and refine the state estimates?

That's what I understand from your question set up and my answer to it is no you cannot. Those new data cannot replace true phsyical measurements. They do not involve **new information** that's called as the **innovations process** of a random process (that you're trying to estimate), hence they cannot be used to make **refined** computations or decisions alone.

In fact, the Kalman filter will only **propagate** the current state $X(t)$ into the next phsyical measurement point $X(t+T_s)$ by using the system **dynamic matrix** alone. (i.e., it will solve the differential equation numerically based on the initial condition provided from the previous state estimate, and **sample** this solution at the requested high data rate)

Comment: Thank you! So perhaps a kalman is not in fact the best approach here? In the interests of clarity, this image:
https://imghost.io/image/dMTQp
 explains a bit more. My data streams in real time, as in the red plotted line. I need to get as close to the blue line as I can, to smooth the animation. i am trying to use a position + velocity * timestep model at the moment, but am searching for a smarter, more predictive way. thanks again.

Comment: yes you can use the Kalman filter perfectly to achive it. It will propagate the state from one red data point to the next as much as it can using the system dynamic equation alone. On the other hand, the blue line seems pretty much a linear one? So you have bunch of other methods to approximate it. The simplest being a linear interpolator. How much accuracy do you need? A Kalman filter estimator could be an overkill, but if you prefer the best accuracy go with the Kalman filter.

Comment: However note that for a **real-time** operation and with **nonstationary** dynamical system (system with **random** (unknown) acceleration) the Kalman estimator needs some time to **converge**. Things go complicated and you must make more detailed analysis of the situation. When you have a **noisy** measurement of **nonstationary** object, there is **no** (imho) perfect solution to it known.

Comment: ok, thanks again. I need all the accuracy i can get, so will keep fighting to wrap my head around the kalman. What other potential methods could be useful here, if i cannot solve it? The motion will be random, in acceleration and velocity (it is a handheld sensor) .

Comment: hmm complicated problem. a Kalman filter will definetely help but the only true solution is to increase the phsiycal sampling rate.

Comment: Not possible I am afraid. Trying to upsample to combat latency is the goal. So added samples in between the measurements is the only option.

Comment: ... Back to your answer, would you be able to suggest a predictor, or a real time interpolation approach? Thanks again for your help

Comment: unlike offline solutions which can process the whole data past-future, real-time interpolation requires **recursive** approaches, since only the current and past data are available. And for **nonstatinary** inputs this is unsolveable. It's like knowing **future**? That being said, you are of course not completely **blind**. Given today's state, you can apprx. **predict** tomorrow's, based on laws that govern the behaviour of the system under concern which is Mechanics for moving particles. Hence Kalman filter solves such a problem the best. You can look for additional IEEE literature, however.